# How to formulate a linear minimization problem with scipy

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, minimize

I have a problem of the form:

min (x1 - k1) + (x2 -k2) + ...

k are constants

with linear constraints:

A*x = B

B's size is 3x1, A is 3xn and x is nx1

I also have linear bounds inequalities in the form

l1 <= x1 <= u1

l2 <= x2 <= u2 ...etc

I'm trying to resolve it in python with scipy :

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import Bounds, minimize, fmin_cobyla

A = \
np.array([[ 0.11,  0.1333,  0.1333,  0.01],
          [ 0.02,  6.667,  0.1333,  0.12],
          [0.0933,  0.6667,  0.6,  0.01]])

B = \
np.array([[25],
          [57],
          [28]])

l = \
np.array([[50],
          [20],
          [5],
          [50]])
u = \
np.array([[200],
          [80],
          [20],
          [200]])

def objfun(x):
    return np.linalg.norm((x - (u-l)/2))


x0 = \
np.array([[1],
          [2],
          [3],
          [4]])

bounds = Bounds(l, u)


eq_cons = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.matmul(A,x)-B}
res = minimize(objfun, x0,  method='SLSQP',
               constraints=[eq_cons], options={'ftol': 1e-9, 'disp': True},
               bounds=bounds)
```

but it gives me the following error:

all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please provide the complete traceback.

Comment: This is classic linear programming. Why use minimize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments and Rorys answer, you should use `scipy.optimize.linprog` for linear problems (LPs), i.e. your objective function and the constraint functions are linear. Only use `scipy.optimize.minimize` for nonlinear problems. The former interfaces sophisticated high-performance solvers (like [HiGHS](https://highs.dev)) for LPs, and thus it will have much better performance in most cases.

That being said, it's also important to stress that minimizing the linear objective function

```
c^T * (x-k) = 1*(x1-k1) + 1*(x2-k2) + ...
```

is **not** equivalent to minimizing the euclidean vector norm of your objective

```
||c^T * (x-k)|| = sqrt( (1*(x1-k1) + 1*(x2-k2) + ...)**2 )
```

as it makes your objective function nonlinear and changes the fundamental properties of your optimization problem. Spoiler alert: your LP is infeasible, i.e. it doesn't have an optimal solution whilst your nonlinear problem (NLP) has one.

Here's a code snippet that solves your LP via `linprog`:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linprog

# Linear constraint A*x = B
A = np.array([[ 0.11,  0.1333,  0.1333,  0.01],
              [ 0.02,  6.667,  0.1333,  0.12],
              [0.0933,  0.6667,  0.6,  0.01]])

B = np.array([25, 57, 28])

# Bounds l <= x <= u
l = np.array([50, 20, 5, 50])
u =  np.array([200, 80, 20, 200])
bounds = [(ll, uu) for ll,uu in zip(l, u)]

# objective f(x) = c^T * x - c^T*k (vector notation)
c = np.ones(4)
k = (u-l)/2

# we minimize c^T*x  s.t.  A*x = B, l <= x <= u
# In order to obtain the objective value of the original LP, we
# simply subtract c^T*k from the objective value res.fun

res = linprog(c, A_ub=None, b_ub=None, A_eq=A, b_eq=B, bounds=bounds)
```

Comment: you're not using k anywhere. And, its important for me to minimize including the constants, not only f(x) = c^T * x. Is it possible with linprog? because thats why I'm not using it.

Comment: @Radu I don't use it because the LPs (1) min c^T * x  s.t.  Ax=b and (2) min c^T * x - c^T*k s.t. Ax=b (note that c^T * k is just a scalar constant) have both the same minimizer. Consequently - as mentioned in the last comment of my code snippet - subtracting c^T * k from the optimal objective function value `res.fun` will yield the optimal objective function value of LP (2).

Comment: Ok. I think I understood. So my result is res.x in both cases, its just in case that I what the value of the objective function. But if I change the problem to  min abs(c^T * x - c^T*k) it makes it nonlinear I guess. Because what I need is to find the values x that are the closest to the constants k.

Answer (score 1):

Your "vectors" must be dimension 1; yours are dimension 2.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import Bounds, minimize, fmin_cobyla

A = \
np.array([[ 0.11,  0.1333,  0.1333,  0.01],
          [ 0.02,  6.667,  0.1333,  0.12],
          [0.0933,  0.6667,  0.6,  0.01]])

B = \
np.array([25,
          57,
          28])

l = \
np.array([50,
          20,
          5,
          50])
u = \
np.array([200,
          80,
          20,
          200])

def objfun(x):
    return np.linalg.norm((x - (u-l)/2))


x0 = \
np.array([1,
          2,
          3,
          4])

bounds = Bounds(l, u)


eq_cons = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.matmul(A,x)-B}
res = minimize(objfun, x0,  method='SLSQP',
               constraints=[eq_cons], options={'ftol': 1e-9, 'disp': True},
               bounds=bounds)

print(res)
```

gives

```
Positive directional derivative for linesearch    (Exit mode 8)
            Current function value: 36.82729965663988
            Iterations: 34
            Function evaluations: 298
            Gradient evaluations: 30
     fun: 36.82729965663988
     jac: array([-0.67884445, -0.27153778, -0.06788445, -0.67884445])
 message: 'Positive directional derivative for linesearch'
    nfev: 298
     nit: 34
    njev: 30
  status: 8
 success: False
       x: array([50., 20.,  5., 50.])
```

This is not my field, but take note of Reinderien's comment: scipy.optimize does have `milp` and `linprog` specifically for linear programming.